# Composer not recognising forked repo to include

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I'm having trouble trying to include a forked open-source repository into my project via composer. I've forked a repository on Github, created a branch, made the relevant changes and am trying to include it via the following through my composer.json file

```
...
"require": {
  ...
  "my-github-name/forked-repo-name": "dev-fix"
  ...
},
"repositories": {
    ...
    "8": {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:my-github-name/forked-repo-name.git"
    },
    ...
```

}
   ...

I've tried including different branches, and release numbers. This is a Magento 2 project, my composer.json file of course has more things, thus the dots I've added to represent items before and after.

I get the following composer error:

```
The requested package my-github-name/forked-repo-name could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

I'm using PHP 7.0.22

The repository isn't private, it can't seem to find it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the output of `composer validate`?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `https` instead of `ssh` in that case:

```
"url": "https://github.com/my-github-name/forked-repo-name.git"
```